# NullReferenceException при попытки вызвать метод через событие

Tags: c#, unity3d

Методы, вызываемые через событие выдают `NullReferenceException`. Причем не в классе в котором было вызвано событие, а в классе где был описан метод

```
public class s: MonoBehaviour   
{   
    public delegate void SpawnPlace();   
    public event SpawnPlace spwnPlc;   
    private void Start()   
    {   
        framePos framePos = new framePos();   
        spwnPlc += framePos.TransFrame;   
    }   
    private void Update()   
    {   
        if (schet.money == 10)   
        {   
           if (spwnPlc != null) spwnPlc();
           //вызываю с проверкой на null   
        }
    }
}
```

класс где описан метод:

```
public class framePos : MonoBehaviour
{   
     
    public void TransFrame()
    {   
        transform.position += cam.transform.forward * 5;
        //NullReferenceException
    }    
}
```

ошибка: NullReferenceException
framePos.TransFrame () (at Assets/scripts/framePos.cs:21)
puller.LateUpdate () (at Assets/scripts/puller.cs:35)

Comment: Пожалуйста укажите полный текст ошибки

Comment: `new framePos()` вы не можете создавать объекты типа `MonoBehaviour` используя конструктор, используйте `Instantiate`. Хотя в данном случае наверное надо написать так `framePos framePos = GetComponent<framePos>();`